# How to handle tell/ask failure of Akka peers?

Tags: java, akka, actor, fault-tolerance

Java API here. Brand new to Akka, and trying to understand how its [Fault Tolerance model](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/fault-tolerance.html) applies to actor messaging that falls *outside* the parent/child or supervisor/supervisee pattern.

If my *understanding* of Akka is correct, one actor can communicate (via `ask(...)` and `tell(...)`) with another actor even if its not that other actor's supervisor. So to me, this means you can have "peer actors" communicating with each other. For instance, perhaps a `FizzRouter` is an actor that is the supervisor of, say, 20 `FizzActor` instances. But each of those `FizzActor` instances may communicate (`tell`/`ask`) with lots of other types of actors, that are merely *peers* and not their actual supervisor.

So `SupervisorStrategies` are wonderful for mapping `Throwables` to `Directives` (stop, restart, resume, escalate), when a (supervised) child is failing. But how do we handle failure when a `tell` or `ask` to one of our so-called "peer" actors throws exceptions? **What would this code look like (again, Java API here)?**

Comment: Why the downvote sans explanation? This isn't a dupe, it shows knowledge over the domain (and hence research), and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (at least as far as understandability and answer-ability goes). I smell a hit and run!

Comment: smeeb have you looked into watch? I am also myself new to akka, but that could possibly be an option

Comment: Thanks @scarpacci (+1) - yes I am familiar with `watch` and `unwatch`, but those only tell you when peers fail asynchronously. They won't help you handle when a `tell()` or `ask()` fail, unless I'm missing something. Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Ahhh I gotcha.  Not sure about tell, but with ask you then call myAsk.onComplete { Success(value) => do something Failure(ex) => do something}.  Not sure if this s on the right track of what you are asking or not.  I will have to look at tell a bit more.

Comment: `tell()` is `fire-and-forget`, so the actor processing this message should handle the error.. In case you want a response you should be using `ask()` and handle the failure.